# How to echo in shell script without executing the result

Tags: shell, echo

I am using this code to print all open files in the specified changelist.

```
while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done < `p4 opened -c $changelist`
```

However, the line also gets executed and I get following error:

```
./do.sh: line 7: //perforce/a.js#24 - edit change 353 (text) by user1: No such file or directory
```

My required output is:

```
//perforce/a.js#24 - edit change 353 (text) by user1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) and [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) *ProcessSubstitution* :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(p4 opened -c $changelist)
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

If not using one of these shells (like  Joseph R. said in comments), use a simple pipe :

```
p4 opened -c $changelist | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Awesome turnaround time! It works. Can you give me an idea of what "< <" is called?

Comment: Btw, this needs a #!/bin/bash instead of #!/bin/sh

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: While, it's true that process substitution is not standard `sh` syntax, it originates in the Korn Shell, not `bash` (though it is also available in `bash` and `zsh`).

Comment: You can also use a simple pipe: `p4 opened -c $changelist | while ...` and avoid the portability issues that come with process substitution.